# pgfplots x-axis scaling to very small size

Tags: pgfplots, diagrams

I've got a problem here. When I use the code like its shown below, it all works fine. BUT if I'm changing the xmax parameter to a smaller value like for example xmax=0.05 there are some errors occurring.

*! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgf/number format/at', to which you passed '(1,0)', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.Type H  for immediate help.... \end{axis}*

! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgf/number format/yshift', towhich you passed '-2em', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.Type H  for immediate help.... \end{axis}

! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgf/number format/left' and Iam going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.Type H  for immediate help.... \end{axis}

! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgf/number format/inner sep',to which you passed '0pt', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelledit.See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.Type H  for immediate help.... \end{axis}

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[german]{babel}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
    font=\footnotesize,
    %line width=1pt,
    %tick style={line width=0.8pt}
    }}
    \pgfplotsset{every axis legend/.append style={at={(0.5,1.03)},anchor=south}}
    \begin{axis}[ticklabel style={
        /pgf/number format/.cd,
  use comma},xlabel={$\sigma$ [-]},ylabel={$\Lambda$ [-]}, grid=major, legend columns=-1, xmin= 0, xmax= 0.1, cycle list name=black white, width= 0.5\textwidth]
    \addplot table {test.dat};
    \legend {Theorie}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption[]{}
    \end{figure}

    \end{document}
```

The data file test.dat looks like:

```
    x   y
    0.0000734405    1.00
    0.000734224 1.00002
    0.00220151  1.00003
    0.003667276 1.00007
    0.005863111 1.00017
    0.00732515  1.00026
    0.0109739   1.00060
    0.014613779 1.00106
    0.021868115 1.00236
    0.02908885  1.00416
```

If someone has an idea to scale the diagram to the right size it would realy help me. Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem occurs, because you are changing the directory (`.cd`) to the `number format`, but then you don't switch it back to `tikz` which causes the above errors. As you easily will agree on, `at`, `yshift`, `left`, and `inner sep` do not belong to the `number format`, but are `tikz` keys.

The second problem can be solved using the `scaled ticks` feature.

Have a look at the following code and the inlcuded comments for more details.
(For simplicity I directly included the data files of `test.dat` into the document itself.)

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfplotsset{
            every axis/.append style={
                font=\footnotesize,
                line width=1pt,
                tick style={line width=0.8pt}
            },
            every axis legend/.append style={
                at={(0.5,1.03)},
                anchor=south,
            },
        }
        \begin{axis}[
            % don't scale `xticks'
            scaled x ticks=false,
            % scale `yticks' by subtracting 1 from the value
            % add "+1" as scale label
            % (the `%' signs are needed to avoid plotting unnecessary white space)
            scaled y ticks=manual:{$+1$}{%
                \pgfmathparse{#1-1}%
            },
            ticklabel style={
                % change "directory" to the number format
                /pgf/number format/.cd,
                    use comma,
                    fixed,
                % change "directory" back to tikz
                /tikz/.cd,
            },
            xticklabel style={
                /pgf/number format/precision=2,
            },
            yticklabel style={
                /pgf/number format/precision=3,
            },
            xlabel={$\sigma$ [--]},
            ylabel={$\Lambda$ [--]},
            grid=major,
            legend columns=-1,
            xmin=0,
            xmax=0.05,
            cycle list name=black white,
            width=0.5\textwidth,
        ]
%            \addplot table {test.dat};
            \addplot table {
                x   y
                0.0000734405    1.00
                0.000734224 1.00002
                0.00220151  1.00003
                0.003667276 1.00007
                0.005863111 1.00017
                0.00732515  1.00026
                0.0109739   1.00060
                0.014613779 1.00106
                0.021868115 1.00236
                0.02908885  1.00416
            };
            \legend {Theorie}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Just for the record: Besides accepting the answer you could also [upvote](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) the answer by clicking on the up-arrow above the number on the left side of the answer.